# What's the install command for Korora linux distro?

Tags: linux, command, installation

I tried to use the apt-get command. Error message says:

> sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: If you're going to go onto Quora to complain about how mean people are on SO, at least make an effort to follow the rules on SO. Learning how to use your computer isn't programming.

Comment: After that quora question, I've reviewed the rules on SO and I want to apologize to you sir and to any member that felt offended. I'm a novice and I've recognized my mistake. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `yum install package_name` or `dnf install package_name` (Dandified Yum).
DNF is faster and uses less memory. It also runs in python 2 and 3.

Comment: What's the difference between that and `dnf install package_name` ?

Comment: `dnf` was the default package installer since Korora 22. Earlier Fedora based Korora versions : `yum`